# Why is Azure Eventhub batch message processing faster than single message processing even if Azure function run parallel?

Tags: c#, azure, parallel-processing, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

Lately, I did performance test of application that uses Azure Function and Azure Event Hub.

Single message processing:

```
pubic async Task Run(EventData msg, CloudTable myTable) 
{
    await myTable.Upsert(msg.ToTableEntity());
}
```

Batch message processing:

```
public async Task Run(EventData[] messages, CloudTable myTable)
{
    var tasks = messages.Select(async msg => await Handle(msg, myTable)).ToList();
    await Tasks.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task Handle(EventData msg, CloudTable myTable)
{
    await myTable.Upsert(msg.ToTabletEntity());
}
```

The speed of batch message processing is faster 15% than single message processing.

I expect they have the same speed because Azure function process message parallel.

I think about the setting of host.json such as: `batchSize`, `prefetchCount`, `checkpoint` impact to this result.

Could you help me to explain?

Thanks,

Comment: Thank for editing. I will notice next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch processing is faster due to it just use binding one time to process multiple Event Hub message.
Binding is reflection, so the more binding, the more CPU consumption.

Answer (score 3):

Batching doesn't stop the Function from scaling out to multiple instances. Assuming you are running both versions on the Consumption or Premium plans, [batch processing is expected](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/processing-100-000-events-per-second-on-azure-functions/) to have a faster processing time.

Maximizing throughput by adjusting the batchSize and prefetch count can make some difference, but is going to take some testing for your particular use case to figure out what the best settings would be.

There are two other things to consider when [scaling outward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan). A spike in traffic won't immediately cause the scale controller to spin up a large number of instances.

1. The scale controller only scales up one instance at a time. There is a timeout period between them of 1 second for HTTP functions and 30 seconds for non-HTTP functions on the Consumption plan. Since a single instance can often process more than one message at a time, this doesn't have a 1:1 correlation with processing rate.
2. Each new instance is going to have a warm up time, and won't be able to accept messages immediately. This can vary, but its usually just a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you for useful information. I'm checking these resources you mentioned.

Comment: Single processing hurt much CPU resource if there are many binding. With batch processing we only need binding one time for batch of messages.